# Emacs exporting org file as PDF in batch mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to export a bunch of org mode files to PDF using emacs in batch mode. So far, only export to html seems to work.

When I export to html I see the following -

> U:\tmp>d:\programs\emacs-23.1\bin\emacs.exe -batch --visit=Changelog.org --funcall org-export-as-html-batch
>
> OVERVIEW
>
> Exporting...
>
> Exporting...
>
> Saving file u:/tmp/Changelog.html...
>
> Wrote u:/tmp/Changelog.html
>
> HTML export done, pushed to kill ring and clipboard

However, there is no function like org-export-as-pdf-batch and so I tried the following.

> U:\tmp>d:\programs\emacs-23.1\bin\emacs.exe -batch --visit=Changelog.org -eval "(org-export-as-pdf \"Changelog.pdf\")"
>
> OVERVIEW
>
> Exporting to PDF...
>
> Exporting to LaTeX...
>
> Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, "Changelog.pdf"

Any ideas on how to export to PDF? My org-mode version is 6.35i with on Emacs 23.1. I'm on WinXP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mistake in calling `org-export-as-pdf`.

First ARG use in calling `org-export-as-latex` and specifies how many levels of the outline should become headlines.

Try without ARG:

> C:\> emacs.exe -batch --visit=Changelog.org --funcall org-export-as-pdf